# Help with bad importing of Wikipedia SVGs into CorelDRAW X7

Tags: vector, svg, corel-draw

I have a found several issues when importing SVG files found on Wikipedia to CorelDRAW X7. Whenever I import one, there are many artifacts or glitches.

Examples are:
[Map of the German Empire within Europe, circa 1914](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:German_Empire_1914.svg) where the German Empire is missing, and UK is moved southwards

[Coat of arms of the Lands of the Holy Hungarian Crown](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Coat_of_arms_of_the_Lands_of_the_Holy_Hungarian_Crown_(1915-1918,_1919-1946).svg) where several elements expand past the image, even pas the visible field.

On their own the SVGs are rendered correctly in Internet Explorer or even in the online SVG Editor.

I look forward as to what may be the cause and the solution to my problem.

Comment: You'll need to ask the folks developing Corel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workarround I found for you is that you download Inkscape https://inkscape.org.

Then save it as eps. Now you can import this eps.

Comment: It is only a workaround, it does work, but I have to play with Inkscape s as to not loose the groupings. But as Scott stated it seems to be a Corel issue, so I shall turn to them.

Comment: Report it and wait till the next version X8 Is on the market... Xo)